# CSS let child always stick to right side of screen outside of parent

Tags: css, css-position, parent-child

Here's a simple portrayal of my problem:

[image: There is a big, Green box on the left and a smaller blue box on the right side of the screen. The small box is a child of the bigger box. There is empty space between the boxes and to the right of the smaller box.]

The smaller box is a child of the bigger box and I want the smaller box to always stick to the right side of the screen, even when the window size changes. The only option that worked are the following properties for the boxes:

```
#bigbox{
    border: 1px solid;
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    background-color: green;
    position: absolute;
}
#smallbox{
    border: 1px solid;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: blue;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
}
```

The issue with this is the blue box will be fixed in its position and always be visible which I dont want.

Comment: So don't position `#bigbox` at all, and position `#smallbox` absolute ...?

Comment: Please show your html or edit your question and use the snippet button `<>`

Answer (score 0):

you can use -ve `z-index` property to smallbox, in this way smallbox will hide behind the bigbox:

```css
#bigbox {
        border: 1px solid;
        height: 400px;
        width: 400px;
        background-color: green;
        position: absolute;
      }

      #smallbox {
        border: 1px solid;
        height: 200px;
        width: 200px;
        background-color: blue;
        position: fixed;
        right: 0;
        z-index: -10;
      }
```

```html
 <div id="bigbox"></div>
 <div id="smallbox"></div>
```

Comment: The OP's description was that the small box was a child of the big box.